Getting sans serif font to work with newtx and pdflatex
This simple document is rendered by pdflatex using serif font (not sans as requested) and I get the warning "Font shape OT1/qhv/m/n undefined":
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{newtx}  
\begin{document}  
\textsf{Hello}  
\end{document}

Adding lmodern does fix the issue. The output is rendered with the same sans face than without using newtx at all:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}    
\usepackage{newtx} % <-- this does nothing in this case 
\begin{document}  
\textsf{Hello}  
\end{document}

So it seems that newtx is using the same sans font than lmodern, but its documentation states:

It is a complete text (newtxtext) and math (newtxmath) package with roman text font provided by a Times clone, sans serif based on a Helvetica clone

So why doesn't it work by itself when using sans fonts?
Here is another quote:

If you specify no sf text or tt text fonts before newtxmath/newtx, those packages will load a Helvetica clone and the typewriter font from txfonts.

So maybe I should install txfonts (I'm using basictex, so it's probably not installed by default), but anyway the first quote seems to imply that the fonts are provided by newtx.
So is txfonts a mandatory newtx dependency?
NOTE: with xelatex and lualatex the first example works OOB.
NOTE: TBH I don't quite understand what newtx does in general.

The first piece of code shows no warning on my machine. Forget about basictex and do a full install.

That's probably good advice, despite my reluctancy to install such monstrosity. Anyway I would like to understand what's missing.

I checked: just Word and Excel occupy 4.5GiB of space on my machine. Add 1.8 GiB for PowerPoint and you have reached about the size of TeX Live.

/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/ot1qhv.fd  so you are missing tlmgr install tex-gyre

@egreg About 2/3 of it? Current TeX Live is about 9G on my machine. Even 2020's is 8G. I assume it is larger on Windows.

The log and/or terminal output tell you what is missing. When a font isn't found it will tell you that and explain the substitution. But it's a mistake to think of it as a dependency. newtx is basically a convenience wrapper which provides a selection of different font configurations. So you only need a font if it is used by the configuration you want to use. Exactly what it does depends on which options you enable and which engine you use to compile your document.

More specifically, qhv is Tex Gyre Heros (the clone of phv, PostScript Helvetica), which is part of the TeX Gyre fonts package. If this problem persists, you could try loading \usepackage{tgheros, newtx}.

@cfr The doc subtree can be removed and is responsible for a lot of space.

@cfr thanks, could you elaborate about "basically a convenience wrapper" a bit, please? Looking at the bundle it does provide some ot and t1 fonts.

@memeplex What I mean is: a lot of the fonts it can load could be loaded without it. You could use TG Heros, for example, with TG Termes or whatever without using newtx. But you'd need to select a set of fonts which worked well together, adjust the scaling of some if need be, and then set them up. That means you need to know which encodings for text and how to configure fonts for mathematics. When all of that's done, you can write \texbf{\itshape\sffamily\large ...} and \[x^2 +1 ....\] and Things Just Work. But you have to do it all. newtx offers a menu of font configurations to pick.
